# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier RequireJS and SVGJS

Tags: javascript, python, svg, flask, requirejs

I am attempting to use RequireJS and SVG.JS together (I happen to be using Flask also but that should not matter for this bug). I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

And the error points to code that looks like this (This appears to be generated somehow by Require or SVG or something). At `VM4803:2` which I believe is generated by Chrome's JS Engine.

```
(function() {
   [object SVGSVGElement]
})
```

Obviously this is not valid code. The code I wrote in a couple of files is as follows.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
    <title>MCB</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var staticJSURL = "{{ url_for('static',filename='js') }}";
</script>
<script data-main="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/app') }}" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/lib/require.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: staticJSURL + '/lib/',
    paths: {
        app: staticJSURL + "/app/",
        svg: staticJSURL + "/lib/svg",
        "svg-grid" : staticJSURL + "/app/helpers/grid"  
    },
    shim: {
        svg: {
            exports: 'SVG'
        },
            'svg-grid': {
                deps: ['svg']
        }
    }
});


requirejs(['app/main']);
```

**main.js**

```
define(['svg','svg-grid'],function (require,grid) {

    var canvasSize = {
        width: window.innerWidth - 16,
        height: window.innerHeight - 16
    }
    var draw = SVG('canvas').size(canvasSize.width,canvasSize.height);
    draw.rect(canvasSize.width,canvasSize.height)
    .stroke({
        width: 1,
        color: "#000"
    })
    .fill({
        color: "#FFF"
    });

    SVG.Grid('100%').start();

});
```

**grid.js**

```
SVG.Grid = function(width, height, cellSize){
    console.log("grid init",width,height,cellSize);
    this.constructor.call(this, SVG.create('svg'));
    this.viewbox(0, 0, 100, 100);
    this.update(0);
}

SVG.Grid.prototype = new SVG.Container;

SVG.extend(SVG.Grid, {
    draw: function() {
        console.log("Draw")
    }

});

SVG.extend(SVG.Container, {
    Grid: function(width, height, cellSize){
        return this.put(new SVG.Grid(size));
    }
});
```

My goal is to just make these files work together without getting errors. Basically I am trying to setup the requirejs structure with svg js. I know this isn't a valid grid and it doesn't show much but I don't understand how to get rid of that error. I tried variations of getting rid of different things in the config. I am sure that all the files are being found because the network tab in Chrome shows a 200 status for all of them.

For completeness sake this is my app.py that flask is running to show the index.html file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```